# Prove or disprove the equality of these two integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $\alpha$ be an arbitrary positive real number in:
$$
F_1 = \int_0^1 x^2 \left[ \int_{-1}^{+1} \frac{e^{-\alpha\sqrt{1+x^2+2xy}}(xy+1)}{(1+x^2+2xy)^{3/2}}dy\right]dx $$ $$
F_2 = \int_1^\infty x^2 \left[ \int_{-1}^{+1} \frac{e^{-\alpha\sqrt{1+x^2-2xy}}(xy-1)}{(1+x^2-2xy)^{3/2}}dy\right]dx
$$
**Prove or disprove that $F_1 = F_2$**.

Source of the problem are the equations (3) and (4) in
[*A Paradox of Newtonian Gravitation and Laplace’s Solution*](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/021/05/0447-0452)
by Amitabha Ghosh and Ujjal Dey.
They have done already numerical experiments that seem to confirm equality.

Quote: *an analytical proof showing that F1 and F2 are exactly equal will be an interesting mathematical exercise.*
And that's it. I have no idea how to proceed.

#### Progress so far

I promised myself not to do numerical experiments.
But the outcome of the inner integral - the one between square brackets - is indeed terrible.
So what else would be an option?
With [MAPLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maple_(software)) 8 some values in the publication can be reproduced.

```
for k from 0 to 10 do
alpha := k*0.1;
g(x,alpha) := int(exp(-alpha*sqrt(1+x^2+2*x*y))*(x*y+1)/(1+x^2+2*x*y)^(3/2),y=-1..1);
F1 := evalf(int(g(x,alpha)*x^2,x=0..1));
F2 := evalf(int(-g(x,alpha)*x^2,x=1..10^3)); 
end do;
```

The special case $\alpha = 0$ gives $\,F_1=\frac{2}{3}\,$ and $\,F_2=0\,$ exactly.
So it appears that nearby $\alpha = 0$ the integrals must be unequal.
But MAPLE keeps calculating endlessly for those low values and I had to manually stop the program.

**[Feynman trick](https://www.cantorsparadise.com/richard-feynmans-integral-trick-e7afae85e25c).**
$F_1$ and $F_2$ are both a function of $\alpha$ . We can take derivatives under the integral sign and see what happens near $\alpha=0$.
$$
\left.\frac{dF_1}{d\alpha}\right|_{\alpha=0} =
- \int_0^1 x^2 \left[ \int_{-1}^{+1} \frac{xy+1}{1+x^2+2xy}dy\right]dx = -\frac{1}{2} \\
\Longrightarrow \quad dF_1 = -\frac{1}{2}d\alpha
$$ $$
\left.\frac{dF_2}{d\alpha}\right|_{\alpha=0} =
- \int_1^\infty x^2 \left[ \int_{-1}^{+1} \frac{xy-1}{1+x^2-2xy}dy\right]dx = \infty \\
\Longrightarrow \quad dF_2 = \infty\,d\alpha
$$
Leading to the following heuristics.
$F_1(\alpha)$ is somewhat decreasing from $F_1(0)=2/3$ to lower values, but the increase in $F_2(0)=0$ is infinitely large at that place.
Based upon this, it's impossible to [keep up appearances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keeping_Up_Appearances) )-:
we can actually say nothing yet whether the outcome is $\,F_1(\alpha) = F_2(\alpha)\,$ for all $\,\alpha \gt 0\,$.

Comment: Just commenting that flipping the $-$ sign is possible since $y\rightarrow -y$ is a symmetry

Comment: @user619894 : Thanks! I've adapted the question accordingly.

Comment: How do you go from the first line of $F_2$ to the second line? Shouldn't it pick up an extra negative sign from the transformation $y\to -y$?

Comment: @HackR : No. I did a check check double check even with MAPLE and it's correct.

Comment: I was looking at the substitution $y=-z$. Then there are 3 places where we get a negative sign from, one from the limits getting swapped, one is $xy-1=-(xz+1)$ and the final one from $dy=-dz$. I am not sure how to get rid of the extra negative sign. 

Wolfram also seems to agree (with x=1) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integration+-1+to+1+of+%28%28exp%28-sqrt%282-2y%29%29%28y-1%29%29%2F%282-2y%29%5E%283%2F2%29%2B%28exp%28-sqrt%282%2B2y%29%29%28y%2B1%29%29%2F%282%2B2y%29%5E%283%2F2%29%29+dy

Comment: @HackR : Sorry. You're quite right. The sign is wrong. I've restored the original question.

Comment: Still might be worth flipping (and multiplying by $-1$ outside) to bring out the similarity. Also, the $x$ integration limits suggest $x \rightarrow 1/u$

Comment: @user619894 : Yes, I've tried that substitution, without success however.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Proof sketch:
\begin{align*}
\frac{{{\rm d}^3 F_1 }}{{{\rm d}\alpha ^3 }} & = -\int_0^1 {x^2 \int_{ - 1}^1 {{\rm e}^{ - \alpha \sqrt {1 + x^2  + 2xy} } (xy + 1){\rm d}y} \,{\rm d}x} \\ & = -\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - 2\alpha } (4\alpha ^4  + 14\alpha ^3  + 27\alpha ^2  + 30\alpha  + 15)}}{{\alpha ^6 }} - \frac{{3(\alpha ^2  - 5)}}{{\alpha ^6 }}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\frac{{{\rm d}^3 F_2 }}{{{\rm d}\alpha ^3 }} & = -\int_1^{ + \infty } {x^2 \int_{ - 1}^1 {{\rm e}^{ - \alpha \sqrt {1 + x^2  - 2xy} } (xy - 1){\rm d}y} \,{\rm d}x} \\ &  = -\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - 2\alpha } (4\alpha ^4  + 14\alpha ^3  + 27\alpha ^2  + 30\alpha  + 15)}}{{\alpha ^6 }} - \frac{{3(\alpha ^2  - 5)}}{{\alpha ^6 }}.
\end{align*}
Thus,
$$
\frac{{{\rm d}^3 (F_1  - F_2 )}}{{{\rm d}\alpha ^3 }} = 0,
$$
i.e., $F_1-F_2$ is a polynomial of degree at most $2$. By changing the variable $y\to -y$ in the definition of $F_2$, we see that
$$
F_1  - F_2  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {x^2 \int_{ - 1}^1 {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - \alpha \sqrt {1 + x^2  + 2xy} } ( xy+1)}}{{(1 + x^2  + 2xy)^{3/2} }}{\rm d}y}\, {\rm d}x} .
$$
The right-hand side tends to $0$ as $\alpha\to +\infty$, i.e., the polynomial $F_1-F_2$ must be the zero polynomial.

Comment: I think u r assuming Taylor series uniformly exists for $F_1-F_2$ as a function of $\alpha$ or $F_1-F_2$ is an analytic function of $\alpha$. Then only u can conclude $F_1-F_2$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq 2$ in $\alpha$. But ur answer is interesting.

Comment: MAPLE says that both derivatives are equal to
$$
{\frac {-15+3\,{\alpha}^{2}+15\,{e^{-2\,\alpha}}+4\,{e^{-2\,\alpha}}{
\alpha}^{4}+30\,{e^{-2\,\alpha}}\alpha+14\,{e^{-2\,\alpha}}{\alpha}^{3
}+27\,{e^{-2\,\alpha}}{\alpha}^{2}}{{\alpha}^{6}}}
$$
So I think there's a typo at $4\alpha^2$ in your formulas. And perhaps minus signs missing in front.
But OK, it's a "proof sketch" and it solves the problem after minor nitpicking. Great!

Comment: @HandeBruijn Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Define
$$ F(\alpha) = \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\pi} {\rm e}^{-\alpha r} \sin \theta \, \cos \theta \, {\rm d}\theta \, {\rm d}r $$

Integrating yields
$$ F(\alpha) = -\frac{1}{\alpha} \left. {\rm e}^{-\alpha r} \right|_{r=0}^\infty \; \cdot \; \frac{1}{2} \left. \sin^2 \theta \right|_{\theta=0}^\pi = 0 \quad \text{for all } \alpha>0, $$
but does not exist for $\alpha = 0$.

Map the function using $u = -r \cos \theta$, $v = r \sin \theta$ and the determinant of the Jacobian
$$ \left| J \right| = \left|
\begin{matrix}
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} = r \sin \theta & \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = -\cos \theta \\
  \frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta} = r \cos \theta & \frac{\partial v}{\partial r} = \sin \theta
\end{matrix} \right| = r$$
This gives
$$ F(\alpha) =
\int_0^\infty \int_0^\pi  \frac{{\rm e}^{-\alpha r} \sin\theta \cos\theta}{r} \, r \, {\rm d}\theta \, {\rm d}r =
\int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{{\rm e}^{-\alpha \sqrt{u^2 +v^2}} uv}{(u^2 +v^2)^{3/2}} \, {\rm d}u \, {\rm d}v 
$$
The integration limits are determined from this map:

[map from r, $\theta$ to u, v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQD05.jpg)

The origin is shifted by one, $u \rightarrow u +1$, to give
$$ F(\alpha) =
\int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{{\rm e}^{-\alpha \sqrt{u^2 +2u +1 +v^2}} (u +1)v}{(u^2 +2u +1 +v^2)^{3/2}} \, {\rm d}u \, {\rm d}v 
$$

Map again using $y = -\cos\theta' = u/\sqrt{u^2 +v^2}$, $x = r' = \sqrt{u^2 +v^2}$, $u = xy$ and the determinant of the Jacobian
$$ \left| J \right| = \left|
\begin{matrix}
  \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = 1/x -u^2/x^3 & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} = -uv/x^3 \\
  \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} = u/x & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} = v/x
\end{matrix} \right| = v/x^2$$

$$ F(\alpha) =
\int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{x^2}{v} \frac{{\rm e}^{-\alpha \sqrt{u^2 +2u +1 +v^2}} (u +1)v}{(u^2 +2u +1 +v^2)^{3/2}} \, \frac{v}{x^2} \, {\rm d}u \, {\rm d}v $$
$$ = \int_0^\infty x^2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{{\rm e}^{-\alpha \sqrt{x^2 +2xy +1}} (xy +1)}{(x^2 +2xy +1)^{3/2}} \, {\rm d}y \, {\rm d}x 
$$
$x$ acts as a radius, $y$ is the fraction of $x$ along $u$.  The integration limits are determined from this map:

[map from u, v to x, y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTQtl.jpg)

This is the same function given above by @Gary, so we have
$$ F(\alpha) = F_1 - F_2 = \int_0^{\infty} x^2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{{\rm e}^{-\alpha \sqrt{1 +x^2 +2xy}} (xy +1)} {(1 +x^2 +2xy)^{3/2}} \, {\rm d}y \, {\rm d}x = 0 \quad \text{for all } \alpha>0, $$
but does not exist for $\alpha = 0$.  Therefore $F_1 = F_2$ for all $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: Your solution looks very interesting (+1).  Thanks!

Comment: I think the "Integrating yields" must be $$F(\alpha) = -\frac{1}{\alpha} \left. {\rm e}^{-\alpha r} \right|_{r=0}^\infty \;\cdot\; \left. \sin^2 \theta \right|_{\theta=0}^\pi = 0
\quad \text{for all } \alpha>0,$$ But for the rest your proof is exactly what I've been looking for since @Gary posted his (computer aided?) answer. You did it entirely by hand. Brilliant!

Comment: @HandeBruijn Thanks, I corrected the equation but kept the 1/2 in front of $\sin^2 \theta$.

Comment: Yes, of course ;-)

Comment: The physics behind it is an application in cosmology: [Seeliger's Paradox](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/cosmology/india.htm) .
Thanks to you I could use the same method with the Jacobians for an alternative calculation with the same outcome.

Comment: Enjoy your 50+. You deserved it!